# Склонение слов по русским падежам

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, почему неверно склоняются слова.

```js
let date = new Date();
let week = ['воскресенье', 'понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота'];
let monthes = ['января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня', 'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря'];

let day = date.getDate(),
  month = monthes[date.getMonth()],
  year = date.getFullYear(),
  dayWeek = week[date.getDay()],
  hours = date.getHours(),
  minutes = date.getMinutes(),
  seconds = date.getSeconds();

function declOfNum(number, titles) {
  let cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
  return titles[(number % 100 > 4 && number % 100 < 20) ? 2 : cases[(number % 10 < 5) ? number % 10 : 5]];
}

console.log('Сегодня ' + day + ' ' + month + ' ' + year + ' года, ' + dayWeek + ', ' + hours + ' ' + declOfNum(5, ['час', 'часа', 'часов']) + ' ' + minutes + ' ' + declOfNum(5, ['минута', 'минуты', 'минут']) + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + declOfNum(5, ['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд']));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... + declOfNum(5, ['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд']));
                ^
```

Почему именно пять?

Comment: И что надо подставить вместо 5? 
Вы можете объяснить, как работает функция declOfNum?

Comment: @win `seconds`, конечно. А Вы? Где Вы ее взяли?

Comment: http://internetbrains.blogspot.com/2010/01/javascript.html

Цитата: "Первый аргумент число, второй - массив с тремя строками.
Массив легко создавать провяряя числа 1, 3 и 5.
Пример: decOfNum(5, ['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд'])"

Comment: @win Вы понимаете смысл первого значения, передающегося в функцию?

Comment: Я поменяла эти пятерки на hours, minutes, seconds и всё корректно стало работать.
Функция declOfNum получает время от компьютера, а потом подставляет слово в нужном формате: "секунд", "секунда" или "секунды".